# What is the closed form for $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ({n})}{n!}$?

Tags: calculus, summation

How do we find the following sum (closed form)?

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ({n})}{n!}$$

Comment: Use (one of) Euler's formulae.

Comment: $\Im e^{e^i} = e^{\cos 1}\sin(\sin 1)$

Comment: If you have a new question, you should click on "ask question" and ask a new one; not edit the previous one.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi This isn't a new question..i know how this is done..i shared it because the answer is so elegant..

Comment: Well then, if this is an answer, you should post it as an answer to your question, and probably add more details...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the identity $\cos(n)+i\sin(n)=(\cos(1)+i\sin(1))^n$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n!}&=\Im\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n)+i\sin(n)}{n!}\\
&=\Im\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(\cos(1)+i\sin(1))^n}{n!}\\
&=\Im e^{\cos(1)+i\sin(1)}\\
&=e^{\cos(1)}\sin(\sin(1)).
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 6):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n!} = \Im\sum\frac{e^{in}}{n!}=\Im e^{e^i}=\Im e^{\cos(1)}e^{i\sin(1)}=e^{\cos(1)}\sin(\sin(1)).$$

Comment: How is this different from the other answer?

Comment: The symbols are different. Perhaps slightly more succinct. I prefer these steps myself.